# Market Mix Modeling using Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, regression-coefficients, marketing, elasticity

I am trying to build a random forest-based market mix model, wherein I want to calculate the contribution of each of my X variables towards the target. Typical MMM problem statement, but here am not sure about how to get this done using random forest In the past I have worked with a typical OLS approach where I can easily get the coefficient/elasticities. But what about the random forest?

Answer (score 0):

You want Athey's casual forests to get the average treatment effect. The calculation of ATE in these settings can be a little tricky otherwise. They've set it up nicely as an R package.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07409

One might think that simply manually calculating a forecast of Y with RF and then manually evaluating $E(Y|X=1)-E(Y|X=0)$ ought to work (by say, setting all the X's to 1 and then setting all X's to 0 and subtracting the difference) but I've found in my practice data sets that such an approach doesn't recover the same estimates.

Comment: Doesn't this approach require a binary treatment, whereas the question is about the effects of varying several continuous Xs (presumably marketing spend across various channels)?